# Why does Spring Boot Actuator return a 404 instead of 401?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

This is a very dumb question but, I don't understand why actuator gives me a 404 instead of a 401 when I try to access a secured endpoint.

I added the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And disabled the security for non-sensitive endpoints

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Now, I can access the application, and (a crippled version of) `/health` but when I go to `/metrics`, it gives me a `WWW-Authenticate` header, good, but with a 404, so my browser doesn't prompt me for user and password.

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8081/metrics
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1090 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying ::1...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1143 (connection #0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1240 (connection #0)
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x6000572d0; line 1258 (connection #0)
> GET /metrics HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x6000572d0; line 1337 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x6000572d0; line 1464 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x6000572d0; line 1474 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Spring"
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 15:55:12 GMT
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x6000572d0; line 1632 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

And the relevant properties in `application.properties`

```
# Spring Boot Actuator
management.address=127.0.0.1
management.port=8081
security.basic.enabled=false
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=a1b2c3
```

Why is that so? Can I change it?

Comment: Could you post your entire configuration file? You should be getting a 401 for all endpoints (even made up ones), except those explicitly not sensitive, like `/health`.

Comment: @adamr I added the properties that I have, if you mean that.

Comment: Assuming your application is running on a different port, can you try running the actuator on the same port as your application and seeing if the metrics works then?

Answer (score 2):

You have set the `management.context-path=/actuator` so all of the Actuator endpoints will be prefixed with this. Your URL should be `localhost:8080/actuator/metrics`

Comment: Sorry, in the first edit I posted a newer version of the properties with `management.context-path=/actuator`. That shouldn't be there and I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you've added spring-boot-starter-web:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. endpoints.health.enabled=false , in application.properties
This was causing issue at my end. I removed this property from application.properties

2.In pom.xml it should be compile in <scope> tag.
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Compile is the default scope. So it's compile if there is no scope tag.